# How to dynamically exclude files from ls output?

Tags: bash, ls

I execute the command:

```
echo $(ls -p "/root/arch" -1tr | grep -v / )
20190107224626.ogg 20190107224705.ogg 20190107224720.ogg 20190107224645.ogg
```

I get the entire list of files, sorted from the oldest (from the date of creation).
Everything works as it should.

It is also necessary to make dynamic exclusions of files (there are files with the same names, but the extension .lock and in a different folder):

```
echo $(ls -p "/root/pids" -1tr | grep -v / )
20190107224645.ogg.lock 20190107224705.ogg.lock
```

I execute the command:

```
echo $(ls -1tr /root/pids/*.lock | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | grep -Po '.*(?=\.)' | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "-I \"$line\" "; done)
-I "20190107224645.ogg" -I "20190107224705.ogg"
```

Now I try to combine all this into one line, but it does not work as it should (I get all 4 files, instead of two), what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
echo $(ls -p "/root/arch" -1tr $(ls -1tr /root/pids/*.lock | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | grep -Po '.*(?=\.)' | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "-I \"$line\" "; done) | grep -v / )
20190107224626.ogg 20190107224705.ogg 20190107224720.ogg 20190107224645.ogg
```

Comment: What is the goal of the final command? Is it to only list the files from /root/arch that do not have a .lock file?

Comment: @AidanLovelace, yes.

Comment: If you want them sorted by date of creation (or do you mean filename, since they are dated numerics?), why are you using `-S`? That should be sorting by size.

Comment: @PaulHodges, I'm already confused with the commands, instead of `-S` I had to use `-tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's one thing I've learned in my short time reading SO questions tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), it's that parsing the output of `ls` is frowned upon.

An alternative approach is below. It iterates over every file in `arch/`, and if it finds no corresponding filename with a `.lock` suffix in `pids/`, it outputs the filename:

```
find arch -type f -printf '%f\0' | while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    if [[ ! -e pids/$line.lock ]]; then
      echo "$line"
    fi
done | sort -n
```

Result:

```
20190107224626.ogg
20190107224720.ogg
```

Comment: `[ $(find ...) ]` isn't great either (there's no knowing how many separate arguments to `[` your `find` results will be split into). And there's no reason for it here: `if [[ -e /root/pids/$line.lock ]]; then echo "$line"; fi` does a perfectly good job.

Comment: ...also, `find ... -printf '%f\n' | while read line` is going to misbehave with filenames ending in whitespace, or filenames containing backslash literals; better to use `find ... -printf '%f\0' | while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do`, which behaves well with all possible names.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Blast.. clearly I need to reread the pitfalls list. I have updated my answer with your recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: Does this sort by file size?

Comment: @PaulHodges Negative.. is that a requirement of OP's that I'm not seeing?

Comment: His `ls` is using `-S`, so I assumed so.

Comment: @PaulHodges Ah, I see.. I agree with your comment on the question that it's unclear exactly what the sorting requirement is.

Comment: I confused you all, the requirement to sort by date of creation, that is, I wanted to use -tr, instead of -S. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple one-liner to do this using stream manipulation:

```
ls -p /root/{arch,pids} | grep -v / | sed 's/\.lock//g' | sort | uniq -u | xargs -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly -

```
echo $(
  for f in /root/arch/*               # get each item
  do n="${f##*/}"                     # strip path
     [[ -e "/root/pids/$n.lock" ]] || # if there's NO matching lock
         printf "%s\n" "$n"           # then print the stripped filename
  done | sort -n                      # through a numeric sort
)                                     # to be stacked on one line by echo
```

Is that missing something?

Comment: Probably, but as a rule I avoid *not* anything when it's easy and doesn't really complicate the logic. YMMV, but it's going to do the evaluation internally either way, so I prefer the way this self-documents. It's a matter of taste. One extra line for clarity isn't a big deal, and gives me somewhere to put a comment out beside it. ;oD  But since you mention it, I also hate bloat, so maybe an *or* is better here.